# CKSDev alternative for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: cksdev

[CKS Dev](https://cksdev.codeplex.com/) does not yet have a version for VS 2015. Can you recommend another tool to quickly update assemblies and layouts pages from Visual Studio 2015 ?

Answer (score 17):

With a trick, you can install CKS Dev for Visual Studio 2015.

1. Download the .vsix-Extension file.
2. Use an archive manager that can open .cab archives, e.g. 7zip or winRAR to open the .vsix file (you might need to rename it to *.cab).
3. Open the extension.vsixmanifest file
4. In the following lines

   ```
   <Installation>
       <InstallationTarget Version="[12.0,13.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
       <InstallationTarget Version="[12.0,13.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate" />
       <InstallationTarget Version="[12.0,13.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium" />
   </Installation>
   ```

   change `Version=[12.0,13.0)"` to `Version="[12.0,15.0)"`
5. Save the file in the archive
6. Potentially rename the file back to .vsix and install the extension.

I can use CKS Dev this way in VS2015 Enterprise.

Comment: Look no further. This is the solution. Thanks FinnO!

Comment: Finno, can you include the link to CKS.Dev.Vs2013.vsix, please? It's not obvious for some people. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c7690381-c0a1-4d37-84ca-915cee25aad8

Comment: You can download the installation file for VS 2015 from here: http://ge.tt/5MiKdra2 I will keep this link working forever

Answer (score 5):

I converted the CKSDEV for VS2013 version to VS2015 and uploaded to Google Drive for all to shaRE. The link above was broken so I thought I would fix that.

[CKSDEV for Visual Studio 2015](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ZcIeYIJoUDOGo3bUFMZkdnQWc/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3):

You can use CKSDev in Visual Studio 2015 also try the work around suggested below

1. Open window explorer and go to \Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions
2. Find the folder containing CKSDev – on my machine it was called yqxmnzzs.3tk
3. Copy the folder.
4. Open window explorer and go to \Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions
5. Paste the copied folder here.
6. Start Visual Studio 2015 (with Office Developer Tools)
7. Click Tools > Extensions and Updates
8. Find CKSDev click Enable it. It is disabled default.
9. Restart Visual Studio 2015.

Hope this will work.