# How to install CKSDev on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: 2016, cksdev, visual-studio-2017

I have a new dev env with SP2016, Win2016, VS2017. Almost all of my work is development of farm solutions, so the process in general is the same since SP2010. On previous env I used CKSDev to speed up the deployment and simplify debugging and I want to continue, however seems that CKSDev development has frozen on VS2013. What can I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

1. Download .vsix package of CKSDev https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WesHackett.CKS-DevforVisualStudio2013
2. Rename it to .zip and use any tool to edit the extension.vsixmanifest inside. Respect to [this question and answers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160304/cksdev-alternative-for-visual-studio-2015)
3. In the manifest add the last entry inside `<Installation></Installation>` tag, 15.0 means the version of Visual Studio 2017 and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community is the SKU, use another if you have Professional or Enterprize

   ```
   <Installation>
       <InstallationTarget Version="[12.0,15.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
       <InstallationTarget Version="[12.0,15.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate" />
       <InstallationTarget Version="[12.0,15.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium" />
       <InstallationTarget Version="15.0" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" />
   </Installation>
   ```
4. Rename the .zip back to .vsix, close VS and start installing.
5. You will get the warning message like [image: VSIX Installer Warning]. Continue on your own risk, but seems that VS2017 respects only extensions with new version of manifest, but allows also old and shows this message every time, so don't worry.
6. VS2017 has a bug that prevents CKSDEv to run, so change in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\devenv.exe.config`
   one assembly version from 14 to 15, seems it is old value for VS2015 by default

   ```
   <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
       <!--bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0"/-->
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0"/>
   </dependentAssembly>
   ```
7. Start VS.

I have a VisualStudio Community 2017 15.0.0+26228.9 and I don't know whether other SKUs or builds have this bug, but you may check on your env.
Also I didn't check all the features of CKSDev, I can do Copy to SharePoint Root - what I need right now. I will update this post if I found any new info.

Comment: I could not make it work with VS 2017 Professional. I'm using <InstallationTarget Version="15.0" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" /> as the last entry, but when I try to double-click the extension file it only shows my old Visual studio 2015 as a target. 2017 Professional is not listed :(

Comment: Works for me - I have used the Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise -
`<InstallationTarget Version="15.0" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" />`

Answer (score 4):

Adding my two cents.

I've uploaded the extensions (VSIX) file [here](http://ge.tt/1WNB12m2).

It should work with all VS 2017 editions:

Contents of the extension.vsixmanifest:

`...

<Installation>
    <InstallationTarget Version="15.0" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="15.0" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="15.0" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="15.0" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="15.0" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" />
</Installation>
...`

Comment: Hi Denis! Can You please re-upload?..

Comment: Hi @GennadyG, sure, but is something wrong with the link above? I've just checked it and it still works fine. I wasn't planning on removing this file from the sharing site.

Comment: Argh.. Something with my connection - it worked, with VPN. Thank You much Denis!)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, in my vs2017 enterprise works!
With some modifications:

1)
`<InstallationTarget Version="15.0" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" />`

2)devenv.exe.config file location is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE`

Answer (score 1):

As of right now, [Oleg's answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/211804/40491) needs three more steps to complete:

I had to copy the extension folder from

```
%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions\<Random name>
```

to

```
%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_<random suffix>\Extensions\<Random name>
```

Additionally, I had to delete the *.CACHE files in the

```
%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions
```

folder.

After a Visual Studio restart, my "*Extension and Updates*" dialog showed the "*CKS - Dev for Visual Studio 2013*" entry, and it even was already activated, but still didn't work right (the context menu on SharePoint project items was still missing). Just disable it, restart Visual Studio, enable it again, restart again, and voilà, the extension works as expected.